# Keeping compactenum counters right-aligned

Tags: horizontal-alignment, lists, paralist

I'm using the compactenum environment (in the paralist package). I'd like to customize the font of the number counter, but when I do so the list ceases to be right-aligned.

In the example below, the first list is fine, but the second (customized) list is now flush left.

> [image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{paralist}

\begin{document}

\begin{compactenum}
\item One
\item Two
\item Three
\item Four
\item Five
\item Six
\item Seven
\item Eight
\item Nine
\item Ten
\item Eleven
\end{compactenum}

\begin{compactenum}[\bfseries 1]
\item One
\item Two
\item Three
\item Four
\item Five
\item Six
\item Seven
\item Eight
\item Nine
\item Ten
\item Eleven
\end{compactenum}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works if you set the custom enum label via the `paralist` specific macro:

```
\setdefaultenum{}{}{}{}
```

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{paralist}

\setdefaultenum{\bfseries1.}{}{}{}
\begin{document}

\begin{compactenum}
\item One
\item Two
\item Three
\item Four
\item Five
\item Six
\item Seven
\item Eight
\item Nine
\item Ten
\item Eleven
\end{compactenum}

\begin{compactenum}
\item One
\item Two
\item Three
\item Four
\item Five
\item Six
\item Seven
\item Eight
\item Nine
\item Ten
\item Eleven
\end{compactenum}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively, the following also works and is local:

```
\begin{compactenum}[1.][10.]
\item One
\item Two
\item Three
\item Four
\item Five
\item Six
\item Seven
\item Eight
\item Nine
\item Ten
\item Eleven
\end{compactenum}
```

where `[10.]` is the widest label

Comment: Right, thanks. Is this not in the documentation, or am I missing something?

Comment: @JohnPeyton I think the relevant part would be "section 3. Formatting the labels" where it explains that sometime you need to specify the widest label for them to fit. It says it's needed for roman numerals, but your question shows it may be needed for other cases too. However I'm not sure why setting the label via the global macro keeps the alignment while setting it locally don't. I think an investigation into source code would be needed to understand why.